# Meaning of "was" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Er arbeitete in einem unterirdischen Raum mit nur zwei Ventilationsschächten, was seiner Gesundheit nicht bekam.

As far as I know, "*was*" means "*what*" or is the contracted form of "*etwas*"

But they wouldn't make sense here, so I guess the meaning should be something like:

> He worked in a room underground..., and that was bad for his health

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. In German, sentences are often much longer than in the English language. 
I think a common translation would be to end the first sentence after "Ventilationsschächten" and start a new one at 'was'. 'Was' would become 'that' here.

> "He worked in a room in the underground with only two ventilation
>   shafts. That was bad for his health."

As already proposed by Emanuel, you can also make a long sentence connecting both parts with "which".

Answer (score 10):

It is a indefinite relative pronoun here, so basically it means "which".

Answer (score 2):

**Was** is a relative pronoun that refers to the whole preceding sentence. Basically one can replace it by ***(und) das***

> Er arbeitete in einem unterirdischen Raum mit nur zwei Ventilationsschächten. ***Das*** bekam seiner Gesundheit nicht.

Example:

> Meine Schüler haben viele Fehler gemacht, was mich sehr enttäuscht hat.
>   Meine Schüler haben viele Fehler gemacht ***und das*** hat mich sehr enttäuscht.